# October CMS - Conditionally Load a Different Page

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm in the process of building a site in October CMS that uses a slash page. The splash page is only supposed to show to non cookied users the first time that they visit the site. I am controlling this part via a component in a plugin called splash. Here is my onRun() function:

```
public function onRun()
{
    $key = 'shownsplash';
    if(!Session::has($key) || !Cookie::get($key))
    {
        $this->page['showsplash'] = true;
        Cookie::queue('shownsplash',true);
        Session::put($key,true);
        $resp = NULL;
    }
}
```

In my main page layout called 'default' I want to conditionally load the splash page template called 'splash' using the following:

```
{% if showsplash %}
     {{ loadpage('splash') }}
{% else %}
     Regular page template
{% endif %}
```

Except that I'm not sure how to load a page conditionally. One additional requirement is that the splash page takes the url **http://www.example.com** and not any subsequent pages. Can anyone point out how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in octobercms cms/page are hit by url , the url set in the config section and are bound to a layout. so for me page are more 'routing' object than html content holder.

In fact partials ARE html content holder

So  if i had to do the same thing as you mean i would use partial and page.
a page with url="/" and two partials, one for the regular page and one for the splash.
bind your plugin component to the page not the layout

```
{% if showsplash %}
    {% partial 'home/splash.htm' %}
{% else %}
    {% partial 'home/regular.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

I think partial are exactly what to use in this kind of conditional stuff.
generaly think of

- layout as website structuration
- page mainly for routing
- partial for html content

Comment: I actually wound up using something very similar. I'll accept this as it does seem to work.